# System.TypeInitializationException while trying to host Cesium locally via nancy in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, nancy, cesiumjs

I'm trying to host a Cesium application (to replace google earth) in C# WPF using Nancy to host.  Trying to get Nancy up and going first and I'm running into this error I can't seem to find an answer for:
"An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occured in Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional Information: the type initializer for 'Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperLocator' threw an exception."

in a public class constructor we call this function:

```
    private void StartNancy()
    {
        string URL = "http://localhost:8080";
        Uri uri= new Uri(URL);
        NancyHost host = new NancyHost(uri);
        host.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Your application is running! on " + URL + 
            "\nPress any [Enter] to close the host.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

I have the relevant using statements:
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

The error is thrown when we try to create the new NancyHost.  Any ideas?

### Thanks!

-Andrew